# Windows Forms (C#) での開発において、項目がnullであった場合にボタンを押せないようにする挙動について

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

現在、Visual StudioのWindows Forms (C#) でプログラムを作成しています。
作成したいプログラムとしては、
・コンボボックスで選択肢から1つ選ぶ
→テキストボックスに数字を入力する
→ボタンを押す
です。

◆実現したいこと
2つの項目に関して、どちらか一方でもNullであった場合にボタンを押せないようにする
（全て入力済でないと、ボタンを押せないようにする）
項目は、1つはコンボボックス、もう1つはテキストボックスです

◆伺いたいこと
上記の機能は実現可能か
実現可能であるならば、どのようなコードを書くことで実装できるのか

まだまだC#の初心者ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

こんな風に考えられます。

- 要望のとおりに押せないようにする

  - 初期状態ではButton.Enabled=falseとする
  - ComboBoxとTextBoxの両方のTextChangedイベントにイベントハンドラを登録する
  - それらのイベントハンドラでは、両方のコントロールのTextプロパティが有効なデータかどうかの判定(IsNullOrEmpty/IsNullOrWhiteSpace)を行い、両方とも有効なデータだった場合にButton.Enabled=trueとする。どちらか一方でも無効なデータだった場合はButton.Enabled=falseとする。
- 押せるが動作しないようにする

  - Buttonのclickイベントのイベントハンドラの先頭で、ComboBoxとTextBoxの両方のTextプロパティが有効なデータかどうかの判定を行い、両方とも有効なデータだった場合にButton押下時の処理を行う。どちらか一方でも無効なデータだった場合は処理は行わず、警告/ガイド表示等を行ってイベントハンドラを終了する。